# Correct response and predictor parameters when using caret and roc()

Tags: r-caret

I'm practicing logistic regression models and cross validation. I would like to output ROC curve to estimate performance, but I'm not sure which response and predictor I should use in the roc() function.
Here is an example I tried. Why are the plots different? What is my error? Thanks.

```
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
library(pROC)

data(mtcars)

mtcars$am = factor(ifelse(mtcars$am == 1, 'one', 'zero'))

ctrl = trainControl(method="cv",number = 5, 
                     summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, classProbs=T, 
                     savePredictions = T)

m=train(am ~ qsec, data = mtcars, method = "glm", 
        family = binomial,metric="ROC",
        trControl=ctrl)


curve1 = roc(response = mtcars$am, 
            predictor = as.numeric(predict(m)), plot = T, legacy.axes = T, percent = T,
            main = 'Test Curve1',
            xlab = 'False Positive Percentage (1 - Specificity)',
            ylab = 'True Positive Percentage (Sensitivity)',print.auc = T, 
            print.auc.x = 100, print.auc.y = 100, col = '#20B2AA', lwd = 4)


curve2 = roc(response = m$pred$obs, 
            predictor = as.numeric(m$pred$pred), plot = T, legacy.axes = T, percent = T,
            main = 'Test Curve2',
            xlab = 'False Positive Percentage (1 - Specificity)',
            ylab = 'True Positive Percentage (Sensitivity)',print.auc = T, 
            print.auc.x = 100, print.auc.y = 100, col = '#20B2AA', lwd = 4)
```